# How much did the production of the Tsar Bomba cost to the Soviets?

Tags: soviet-union, economy, cold-war, nuclear-weapons

The [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba), also known as the "King of Bombs," was the most powerful nuclear weapon ever detonated. Developed and tested by the Soviet Union during the height of the Cold War, this colossal hydrogen bomb had a yield of 50 megatons, equivalent to 50 million tons of TNT. However, one question still lingers among history enthusiasts and military analysts. What was the financial cost of producing such a massive and devastating weapon?

Comment: How do you put a price on the information that their spies stole from the U.S.? Research is a lot cheaper when someone else is paying for it.

Comment: @SteveBird, you figure out how much the spies were paid.

Comment: This is a very non-Soviet way of thinking

Comment: I suspect that the bomb itself was not particularly expensive, being just another product of the USSR's nuclear weapons program. (Though you could argue that it wasted expensive manpower better spent on other projects.) The very large weight suggests that they had not done a great deal to optimize the bomb -- had there actually been a practical use for something that powerful, it would have been a long and probably expensive process to bring its weight down to the point it could be lobbed around the world.

Comment: How do you measure costs in the Soviet economy? None of the numbers can be correlated to anything in a market economy.  And the notion that we would include the fee paid to the spies is  ... difficult to comprehend. I assume it was offered in jest

Comment: You may want to read Cosma Shalizi's review of *Red Plenty* — [In Soviet Union, optimization problem solves you](https://crookedtimber.org/2012/05/30/in-soviet-union-optimization-problem-solves-you) (2012)

Comment: @MCW "None of the numbers can be correlated to anything in a market economy": well, we could go by purchasing parity - take the project's budget and evaluate the amount of consumer goods of similar cost, preferrably something USSR exported. The real problem is that judging by other Soviet nuclear projects, we are unlikely to have that budget published earlier than 2036.